# How do I add multiple tables using one model and one view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to have a page where the user selects from a drop down list the category, then adds a small text about that category and uploads an image where the path of that image is saved in the database rather than the whole image. I have created a table "Categories" where the admin is authorized to fill it and the user only selects from the categories list.

Here is what I have done so far:

The create categories model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DemoIdentity.Models
{
    public class CategoriesAdmin
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "category name")]
        public string categoryName { get; set; }
    }

    public class DefaultConnection:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CategoriesAdmin> categories { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now I want to have another table (Data) which includes (ID, Category (category name selected from table categories), News, Image_Path). This table is in the Default Connection database. The category name is the selected category name from a drop down list, and the image path is an upload image which saves the path rather than the whole image.

I am unsure of how to achieve this.

Comment: If your Database is in `MS SQL Server` then just use `Stored Procedure ` to save needed Data.

Comment: Im using model in mvc to create the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are confusing components of [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework).

As the Entity Framework site states:

> Entity Framework (EF) is an object-relational mapper that enables .NET
>   developers to work with relational data using domain-specific objects.
>   It eliminates the need for most of the data-access code that
>   developers usually need to write.

And the MVC site states that:

> The ASP.NET MVC is an open source web application framework that
>   implements the model–view–controller (MVC) pattern.

The two frameworks meet through your model classes. MVC uses the model class to define the data, logic and rules of the application. In Entity Framework, your model class is mapped to tables in your database where it handles the direct reads and writes for you.

By creating your `CategoriesAdmin` model class and exposing it as a property in your `DbContext` class as such:

```
public class DefaultConnection:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CategoriesAdmin> categories { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework will have mapped your model class to a database table called CategoriesAdmins. If this table does not yet exist in your database, it will automatically create it for you. This approach in Entity Framework is known as [Code First to a new Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542).

Now since you already have a table that stores the available categories (`CategoriesAdmin`), you will need to create a second model class (called `Data` for the sake your example) which contains properties for the other bits of information that you want to store.

```
public class Data
{
      // gets or sets the ID of this Data record.
      public int ID {get;set;}

      public string ImagePath {get;set;}

      // other properties
      ...
}
```

Now that you have two model classes, you need to create a relationship between the two. In a SQL database this is achieved by Foreign Keys. In Entity Framework, you can achieve the same by using [Navigational Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj713564.aspx).

So we update the `Data` model class as such:

```
public class Data
{
      // gets or sets the ID of this Data record.
      public int ID {get;set;}

      public string ImagePath {get;set;}

      // gets or sets the ID of the related CategoriesAdmin record.
      public int CategoriesAdminId {get;set;}

      // gets or sets the related CategoriesAdmin record. Entity Framework will
      // automatically populate this property with an object for the related
      // CategoriesAdmin record.
      [ForeignKey("CategoriesAdminId")]
      public virtual CategoriesAdmin CategoriesAdmin {get;set;}

      // other properties
      ...
}
```

The [ForeignKeyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `CategoriesAdmin` property is there to give Entity Framework a further hint of the foreign key column to load the navigational property from.

Finally to be able to use your new `Data` model class with Entity Framework, you need to add another property to your `DbContext` class so that you have a means of accessing your data:

```
public class DefaultConnection:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CategoriesAdmin> Categories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Data> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Now that you have created your model classes and wired them into Entity Framework, you will now be able to use them in MVC. If you load your `Data` model into your view (using `DefaultConnection.Data`), you will be able to access the related CategoriesAdmin record by accessing the `CategoriesAdmin` property on the `Data` object.

**In short:** two tables means you need two models. Both models can be loaded into the single view.

**Footnote:** Apologies if there are large gaps in my answer as there is a lot to explain that have already been explained in other places far better than what I can. The references I have linked should hopefully fill in the gaps.

Should you need more help, please see all of [the tutorials on the ASP.NET MVC website on working with data](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-(data)). They're much better written than my concise attempt. I would recommend following them exactly and getting the examples to work before completing your own project so that you have a better understanding of how the two frameworks work and interact with each other.